# Bootstrap Inappropriate Form Formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I changed Bootstrap form class from `form-horizontal` to `form-inline` and all formatting was disturbed. How can I get proper inline formatting?

**Before**
[image: Before Inline]

**After inline**
[image: After inline]

This Is Sample Code Of With First Form Field

```
<div class="form-horizontal">

    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Med_Name">Medicine Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Med_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Med_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    @* Rest Of The HTML Code Is Not Shown *@
```

Comment: Can you please share your HTML?

Comment: See.. When you set `inline` try also to wrap in proper `col-md-*` classes as per your need.. :)

Comment: Sure @AliJamal I will with some detail.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set style to `inline` you also need to wrap it in respective UI patterns say.. Wrapping first 3 `textboxes` in `col-md-4` and then wrap all these 3 `textboxes` in `col-md-12` as parent for them.. Or even you can try to wrap it in `row` element for each 3 `textboxes` or as per your requirements.

**Ex:**

```
<div class="col-md-12"> <!--Even row instead of col-md-12-->
    <div class="form-group col-md-4"> <!--col-md-4 for other elements too-->
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Med_Name">Trade Price</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Med_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Med_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Same goes for other 2 elements-->
</div>
<div class="col-md-12"> <!--Even row instead of col-md-12-->
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Med_Name">Medicine Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Med_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Med_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Same goes for other 2 elements-->
</div>
```